# CMake: Linking Fortran against static C library fails

Tags: c, cmake, linker, fortran, linker-errors

Using CMake and GCC to build a very basic Fortran project with an `iso_c_binding` fails at linking stage. Compiling and linking manually just works fine:

```
$ gcc6 -c getkey.c
$ gfortran6 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc6/ -o key key.f08 getkey.o
```

The minimal `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(GetKey)
set(VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER "gfortran6")
set(GCC_LIB "-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc6")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} ${GCC_LIB}")
enable_language(Fortran)

add_library(getkey STATIC getkey.c)
add_executable(key key.f08)

set_target_properties(key PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)
target_link_libraries(key getkey)
```

Building the project leads to the following linker error:

```
[...]
[100%] Linking Fortran executable key
/usr/lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/usr/src/lib/csu/amd64/crt1.c:(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The linker seems to search for a `main()` function, that Fortran does not feature. Trying to force the Fortran linker makes no difference:

```
set(CMAKE_Fortran_LINKER_PREFERENCE 100)
set(CMAKE_C_LINKER_PREFERENCE_PROPAGATES False)
```

Help is appreciated.

## Example Code

The linker error does not depend on the actual implementation. Anyway, a basic example would be:

`key.f08`:

```
program main
    implicit none

    interface
        function get_key() bind(c, name='get_key')
            use iso_c_binding
            integer(kind=c_int) :: get_key
        end function get_key
    end interface

    write(*, '(i0)') get_key()
end program main
```

And the `getkey.c`:

```
int get_key()
{
    return 10000;
}
```

## Verbose Make

Running `make VERBOSE=1`:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake -H"/home/user/fortran" -B"/home/user/fortran" --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start "/home/user/fortran/CMakeFiles" "/home/user/fortran/CMakeFiles/progress.marks"
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make -f CMakeFiles/key.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/key.dir/depend
cd "/home/user/fortran" && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" "/home/user/fortran" "/home/user/fortran" "/home/user/fortran" "/home/user/fortran" "/home/user/fortran/CMakeFiles/key.dir/DependInfo.cmake" --color=
make -f CMakeFiles/key.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/key.dir/build
[ 50%] Linking Fortran executable key
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/key.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/local/bin/gfortran6    CMakeFiles/key.dir/getkey.c.o  -o key
/usr/lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/usr/src/lib/csu/amd64/crt1.c:(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[2]: stopped in /usr/home/user/fortran
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/home/user/fortran
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/home/user/fortran
```

Comment: Your Fortran project has a main program?  (Can you provide minimal code as an example?)

Comment: Contrary to C, there is no such thing like a main function in Fortran, that is why I guess the C linker is called instead of the Fortran one to link the project. Forcing the use of the Fortran linker did not work.

Comment: Fortran absolutely has the concept of a main program.

Comment: Yes, but there is no `int main()` in Fortran. The linker error occurs on every project where Fortran code is mixed with another language (e.g., C). The specific implementation is therefore of marginal importance.

Comment: Run `make VERBOSE=1` and show us what commands CMake is executing.  Also, have you tried just putting the two source files directly into `add_executable()` and removing `add_library()`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the verbose make output:

```
/usr/local/bin/gfortran6    CMakeFiles/key.dir/getkey.c.o  -o key
```

You are not building with the Fortran code at all!  This is because CMake doesn't recognize .f08 as a code extension.  See here: [cmake, fortran 2008, and .f08 file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005017/cmake-fortran-2008-and-f08-file-extension)

You may simply rename your `.f08` file to `.f` (or `.f90` as described in comments below).

Comment: Renaming to `.f` is a very bad idea! All compilers I know treat .f as a fixed form source by default whereas .f08 is likely to be a free form source. The correct extension for free form files is .f90. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269076/correct-suffix-for-fortran-2003-source-file-intel-fortran-compiler  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884260/how-can-gfortran-tell-if-i-am-compiling-f90-or-f95-code

Comment: @VladimirF: Compiler options can also be used to indicate which form the source file has (I assume you know this).

Comment: Yes, but it is an unnecessary complication. Especially when you have a mixture (my case, can happen easily) and have to put different options to different files. Naming it .f is confusing at best. A very bad idea IMHO.

Comment: @VladimirF: While I do not agree that using `.f` is "a very bad idea," I do think using `.f90` makes sense on some systems including GCC.  I've updated my answer to mention it.