# Is there a way I can successfully import the fortran roll_dice.f95 subroutine file into the main.f95 file?

Tags: file, import, fortran

I am working with Fortran for the first time and I am trying to create two separate files. (1: main.f95 and 2: roll_dice.f95) I would like the main function to import the roll_dice.f95 subroutine file into the main file and execute it to create a more modular and organized program all together. (The roll dice subroutine is one of many for a Casino Craps program).

To start with the main file, I named it 'main.f95' and this is the code I created for it.

```
program main
    implicit none

    ! Declare any variables or use statements here

    include 'roll_dice.f95' ! Include the subroutine file

    call roll_dice() ! Call the subroutine

end program main
```

I expected this file to import my roll_dice.f95 file and execute it.

Here is my roll_dice.f95 file code.

```
subroutine roll_dice()
    real :: r(2)
    integer :: i(2)

    call random_seed()
    call random_number(r)

    ! Convert random real numbers to integers in the range 1 to 6
    i = 1 + nint(5 * r)

    ! Create a select case for the first random number
    select case (i(1))
    case (1)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "|        |"
        print *, "|   *    |"
        print *, "|        |"
        print *, "+-------+"
    case (2)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "|     * |"
        print *, "|       |"
        print *, "| *     |"
        print *, "+-------+"
    case (3)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "|     * |"
        print *, "|   *   |"
        print *, "| *     |"
        print *, "+-------+"
    case (4)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "|       |"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "+-------+"
    case (5)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "|   *   |"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "+-------+"
    case (6)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "+-------+"
    case default
        print *, "Invalid value for the first random number"
    end select

    ! Create a select case for the second random number
    select case (i(2))
    case (1)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "|       |"
        print *, "|   *   |"
        print *, "|       |"
        print *, "+-------+"
    case (2)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "|     * |"
        print *, "|       |"
        print *, "| *     |"
        print *, "+-------+"
    case (3)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "|     * |"
        print *, "|   *   |"
        print *, "| *     |"
        print *, "+-------+"
    case (4)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "|       |"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "+-------+"
    case (5)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "|   *   |"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "+-------+"
    case (6)
        print *, "+-------+"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "| *   * |"
        print *, "+-------+"

    case default
        print *, "Invalid value for the second random number"
    end select
    print "('You rolled a ', 5(i0, ' and ', i0))", i

end subroutine roll_dice
```

When I run the main file I get these errors.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
roll_dice.f95:1:0:

    1 | subroutine roll_dice()
      | 
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
roll_dice.f95:97:3:

   97 | end subroutine roll_dice
      |   1
Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way I can successfully import the roll_dice.f95 subroutine file into the main file?

Comment: I recommend not using the .f95 file extension and use .f90 instead. Some compilers will bot recognize .f95 by default and .f90 became the de-facto standard for free-form Fortran. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269076/correct-suffix-for-fortran-2003-source-file-intel-fortran-compiler

Comment: There's no need to include the other file.  You should be able to compile the two files separately and link the resulting object files together.  Note that you won't get any usage checking if you do so, but in this case, there aren't any arguments so no opportunities for a mismatch.  (There are several alternatives to get usage checking.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a subroutine at an arbitrary place of the main program. Fortran subroutines have their exact locations they are allowed to be. The `include` statement just copies the text from the file to the location of the file, nothing more.

You can have an external subroutine and then the `include` must be outside of the main program. Either before or after, not inside.

You can have an internal subroutine, but then the include must be after `contains` and before `end program`.

You can have a module subroutine, but then you have to create a module. That is preferred way of working with subroutines in modern Fortran. For *"more modular and organized program all together"* that is the way to go, but requires a little study.

As Craig mentioned in a comment, you do not need the include at all. External subroutines can be in any source file, it does not matter. You can compile the files separately and link later or in one go and it works almost exactly the same (with small exceptions for checks and optimizations).

So if you remove the `include`, just

```
gfortran roll_dice.f95 main.f95
```

should work. Similarly for other compilers.