# cmake, fortran 2008, and .f08 file extension

Tags: cmake, fortran

I am trying to configure a Fortran 2008 project to use CMake; the files in the project have the ".f08" extension.  However, I cannot get CMake to work even with a "hello world" example.  Here are the relevant parts of my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project (hello)
enable_language (Fortran)

set (CMAKE_Fortran_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS ${CMAKE_Fortran_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS} "f08;F08")

add_executable ("hello-world" "hello-world.f08")
set_target_properties (hello-world PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)
```

Three notes:

1. The Makefile generated does not compile "hello-world.f08" into an object file.
2. The "set_target_properties" is needed.  Otherwise, CMake reports that it "can not determine linker language for target:hello-world".
3. Renaming the file to "hello-world.f95" along with the corresponding change in CMakeLists.txt makes things work.  Even the "set_target_properties" command is no longer needed.

Comment: Just give free form Fortran source files the `.f90` extension.  Using the extension to indicate the language standard level is generally regarded as a mistake.

Comment: To add to @IanH some compilers will reject extension like .f08.  In particular, `ifort` will complain with `ld:testf08.f08: file format not recognized; treating as linker script` and fail without even trying to compile.  Use `.f90` and use your FFLAGS to put in the `-std=f2008`(gfortran) which will actually use the F2008 standard, unlike counting on the extension to do so.

Comment: Do you rename all files every time you add a feature from a new standard?

Comment: Also see [How to use gfortran for .f90 file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40034609/608639), [How can gfortran tell if I am compiling f90 or f95 code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10884260/608639), [Makefile with different source types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8940552/608639), [Correct suffix for Fortran 2003 source file - Intel Fortran compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20269076/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to specify Fortran files with unrecognized extensions, you can [set](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html) the source file's [`LANGUAGE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/LANGUAGE.html) property, e.g.:

```
set_source_files_properties(hello-world.f08 PROPERTIES LANGUAGE Fortran)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> ifx /extfor:f08 /free main.f08

Since ifort is now deprecated i used ifx.

But using  `/extfor:f08 /free` compiler option is a non-standard way.