# How to use gfortran for Fortran 90 with .for file extension?

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

After I installed Gfortran in Ubuntu (16.04) is pointing to f95. I see in gfortran manual that -std option can be given for f95 and forward. The default `-std` option value I see from manual is "gnu". I am not sure of implications of internals of compiling if I use f95 for f90 code.

How do I use gfortran for Fortran 90 files with .for extension? I do not want to use Fortran 95 compiler for Fortran 90 code though Fortran 95 might be able to (not sure) compile Fortran 90.

Comment: @jww You changed the meaning.

Comment: @VladimirF - Well, I moved the third sentence to the second to improve flow. Then I added a paragraph break. I'm not sure how it broke the meaning, but Fortran is not my specialty. Perhaps you can perform an edit to fix it?

Comment: @jww It was about the .for extension and you changed it to .f90 extension.

Comment: @VladimirF - Please fix the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortran 90 is dead. It had serious deficiencies, especially with allocatables, that were fixed by Fortran 95. For example, it allowed existence of undefined allocation ststus.

Many times someone says he is using Fortran 90 he is in fact using something else.

Fortran 90 and Fortran 95 are so close that there is even no option to enable Fortran 90 in compilers. It would mostly just enable those errors and oversights in the standard and disable just a few features.

Gfortran, in the default mode `gnu` is actually close to a Fortran 2003 or 2008 compiler. Some of the default settings are different from Fortran 90 and 95. For example the automatic re-allocation on assignment. But it is normally good for programs in Fortran 90 and 95 and even some in 77. It enables certain common extensions to the standard. Certsin less common extensions can be enabled by special flags.

There is no reason to worry. Fortran 95 is the standard people should care about. Fortran 90 is not.

Regarding the .for extension, the compiler should process correctly if it is conforming fixed form source, be it 77, 90, 95, 2008, whatever.

Comment: to say F90 is dead makes as little sense as saying that F66 is dead. The compilers generally are backwards compatible to the beginning when Baccus first came out with FORTRAN. Whether there were features in F95 that are needed or not, there is little difference between them in general. It is true that one can say .F95, or .F03, but one can also use .F90 syntax in a file with a .for suffix and other than free or fixed form it is the same (new) compiler that gobbles it up.

Comment: You are wrong. There is a big difference between F66 and F90 situation. I am not saying that F95 is dead because we have F2003, for example. I am not even saying F77 is dead. F90 is dead because it was soon enough fixed by F95. And believe me, F90 was **seriously** wrong about allocatable arrays.

Comment: Syntax does not belong here at all. You can write fixed form Fortan 2008 with only FORTRAN 77 features if you want. It's up to you. Fixed and free form are both perfectly allowed standard forms. (not so in F2015)

Comment: @VladimirF : Do you think you can consider writing an entry in the Fortran documentation about what you said on F90 "wrong about allocatable" and more generally about the difference between Fortran standards, I think that would be very helpful to see the subtle differences between F90 and others.

Comment: The are all touted as modern in way that implies the ones before were antiquated. In reality fortran continues to evolve. So can one really use F90 with a new gfortran or ifort compiler? And calling the file .F90 or .F95, or .F03 has no effect upon the compiler except for the free and fixed aspects. I pretty do as @IanH mentions using .for for legacy code, and .F90 for newer code, but also use -fixed-form when I need D-lines during development and debug.

Comment: I do the same. Why is that relevant?

Comment: Now I understand:

Comment: Now I understand:    .for extension doesnt depict any version (not considering fortran versions after 95). .for only indicates fixed form code and fortran 90 or 95 syntax/code can be written in fixed form too as well as free form. At last, fortran 95 compiler well can be used for fortran 90 code with least impact. Right?

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, the common conventions are: `.f` or `.for` for fixed-form source code, `.f90` for free-form source code, `.F`, `.F90` (on UNIX/Linux) for fixed-form or free-form source code that must be preprocessed in a C/C++ like style using Macros, e.g., `#define BLAH_BLAH = 42`.

Now, while the notion of a "file extension" is ubiquitous on Windows platforms, other platforms such as UNIX/Linux/Mac OS do not attach any special meaning to the last bit of a file name. In fact, Mac OS doesn't even distinguish between `main.f` or `MAIN.F`, they are in fact equivalent.

Second, unlike Java, C/C++, Python, etc, there is no concept of a file as an organizational unit for the source code in FORTRAN/Fortran. More specifically, there can be no code outside the `program`, `subroutine`, `function`, or `(sub)module`, whence; the ISO Fortran standard itself does not define any extension, it does not even prescribe the use of files on disk to represent the source code. This may seem odd at first, but there are good reasons for this: an operating system might use a database of some sort to store all information in, so if the standard prescribed files on disk as the medium, it would exclude such (pre-command line/terminal) systems.

Generally speaking, the extensions `.f90`, `.f95`, `.f03`, and `.f08` are used for modern, free-form source code conforming to the Fortran 90, Fortran 95, Fortran 2003, and Fortran 2008 standards, respectively. For older, fixed-form code, such as FORTRAN 77, the `.f` or `.for` extensions are typically used.

I highly advise against using the `.f95`, `.f03`, `.f08` file extensions (not to mention `.f15`). Not only are these extension not recognized by all compilers, but Fortran 2008 code can be still be written as fixed-form source; it’s still part of that standard.

Therefore, always use `*.f90` to indicate free-form source code.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between `f90` and `f95` are really minor, but with the extension `.for` or `.f`, gfortran expects the code to be in fixed-form.

Try adding the `-ffree-form` option to the compiler.

That said, I'd recommend to have the file extension `.f90` for free-form Fortran code. It will make things much easier in the long run.

Comment: Most conforming Fortran 90 is also conforming Fortran 95, Fortran 2003, Fortran 2008 and will be Fortran 2015.  So as a consequence of the recommendation in the last sentence, do you expect people to rename all their files every time a new standard comes out?  What about the intermediate technical specifications?  That recommendation is really just a recipe for confusion, and there are plenty of posts to support that.  Just take .f90 to mean "the free source form that was first introduced in Fortran 90" and therefore use it for free form source, regardless of the standard being targeted.

Comment: @IanH your comment makes sense. I have reworded that part.